# How to set Replication Factor in multi data center Datasatx cassandra

Tags: cassandra, replication, datastax-enterprise

My Architecture is as follows:

Two data centers DC1 and DC2 in my test cluster named Test Cluster1, DC1 has two spark nodes and DC2 has two transactional(data) nodes, that is i have 4 nodes in my cluster.Then my doubt is that is it possible to set a replication factor of 3 to DC1 or DC2.

Answer (score 2):

No, as RF is set per DC, then you can't RF higher than you have nodes in this particular DC - you need to use `NetworkTopologyStrategy` as this:

```
{'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1':2, 'DC2':2 }
```

Comment: I have one more question about electing seeds.Is this also set per DC, if No what will be the benefit.

Comment: You need to include nodes from DCs into the seed list - otherwise they won't see each other... (Ref: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/initialize/initMultipleDS.html)

Answer (score 1):

The replication factor should be equal to or less than the number of nodes in a data center. As you have 2-2 nodes in each `dc`, you can set 2 as RF while altering the Keyspace in the below manner:

`cqlsh> ALTER KEYSPACE <KS NAME> WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy' , DC1:2, DC2:2};`